# Sliding an element "up" over another as the user scrolls down, without fixed positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

The wording in the title is weird, apologies. It's hard to explain the effect.

I currently have this, it works best on Chrome:
http://mattluckhurst.com/dev/

My client wants each panel to slide up as the user scrolls down, covering the previous panel. I am currently accomplishing this by setting the "current" panel to have `position:fixed` and `top:0` as soon as the page scrolls to it. The panels each have a `z-index` that corresponds to their vertical position on the page. So ideally:

You scroll down. when the next panel is halfway up the window, the scroll animates to get you all the way there, then that panel is snapped to the top so the next one can come in over it.

It's working pretty well in Chrome, but I am getting a lot of flickering and stuff elsewhere. Also on mobile it's a mess, but we really want a nice smooth swipe up down.

I know `fixed` elements can get pretty funky on mobile, so I am wondering if that is the problem, or if I should be using something other than just window scrolling for the animation / effect.

I see more complex parallax stuff all the time, so this should be pretty doable, I'm just not sure where to start.

Thanks for any help! Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0):

A few libraries that might help you:

- https://github.com/dirkgroenen/jQuery-viewport-checker
- https://github.com/janpaepke/ScrollMagic
- https://github.com/matthieua/WOW
- https://github.com/jlmakes/scrollReveal.js
- https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr